# how to find the unequal probability of each value of a die and hence its expected value?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, discrete-mathematics

Lets say that expected value is defined as follows: Let X be a random variable, ie. X can take a value from a set of real numbers, U = {R1, R2, R3, ... ,Rn} in a
random manner.

Example: let X be the number when a 6-sided die is rolled. Each time the die is rolled, X takes one value from the set U = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}.

Further suppose that X takes value xi with probability pi. To be valid probabilities, each pi is a real number such that pi is between 0 and 1 inclusive, and they must sum to unity:(sum of all probability is 1)

We say that P(X = xi) = pi, that is, the probability that X takes the value xi is pi. Example:
for a fair 6-sided die, P(X = xi) = 1/6, for xi is a member of the set U.

suppose that I have a fair 6-sided die, the expected value E[X] would be E[X] = 
(1/6)(1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6) = 3.5

what if i have a biased (unfair) 6-sided die, and let X be the number when it is rolled once. The probabilities are given by: P(X = xi) = ki, for i = 1,2.... 6, where k is an unknown constant.

K would refer to the outcome for each possible value of the unfair die right? How would I find K so that i can find the expected value of this unfair die?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guide:

- Use the property that "they must sum to unity" to find $k$.
- $k$ is the normalizing constant to ensure that the above properties hold.

Comment: this would be: k1+k2+k3+...+k6 = 1. but How would i proceed from here onwards?

Comment: just checking, do you mean $k_i$ or $k i$, the first one or second one?  [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/306553) guide to type maths on the site.

Comment: i mean the second one. Thanks for the mathjax guide.

Comment: can you simplify $k+2k+3k+4k+5k+6k$?

Comment: do you mean that K = $\frac{1}{21}$

Comment: Yes, congratulations.